How to sign a VSIX archive with a YubiKey cert?
I have a code signing certificate on a YubiKey (YubiKey 5C NFC FIPS, PIV Authentication on Slot 9a), in line with the new requirements for code signing certs. I need to sign my VSIX archive for distribution on the Visual Studio Marketplace.
According to the official Visual Studio docs, the new tool for signing the VSIX archive is 'sign': https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/dotnet-sign-cli-reference-vsix?view=vs-2022.
However, when I follow the above guide I receive this error:
Invalid value for --certificate-fingerprint. The value must be a SHA-256, SHA-384, or SHA-512 certificate fingerprint (in hexadecimal).
I am using the certificate thumbprint for --certificate-fingerprint. Is that correct? The guide also mentions running Get-FileHash on a .cer file to determine the fingerprint. However, I don't have a .cer file. Perhaps I need to export one from certmgr or the YubiKey manager? I figured the fingerprint would be used to identify the cert within the certificate store/provider, which is why I've assumed the thumbprint is this ID.
I'm also unsure which value to pass for the --crypto-service-provider. The guide shows various values in the examples, but also advises running certutil -csplist to see all the provider types available, but it's still not clear which one I should choose. I feel like I should be seeing some kind of YubiKey provider, but I do not. How do I figure out which provider to pass to the tool?
I am able to use the YubiKey cert to sign a DLL using the sign.exe tool, so it seems like the cert is correctly configured on the YubiKey. If I try to sign the VSIX file using the old tool (OpenVsixSignTool), I receive a STATUS_HEAP_CORRUPTION (-1073740940) exit code.
I'm hoping someone has been able to successfully sign a VSIX file using a digital cert / YubiKey and can provide some guidance.

The recommended CSP to use is the "Microsoft Smart Card Key Storage Provider”. Did you install the YubiKey minidriver? See also https://support.yubico.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015654900-Smart-Card-Basic-Troubleshooting

Yes, the certificate can also be exported using yubikey manager. If you view the certificate, it will show the fingerprint as a 64-character SHA-256 hexstring

Thanks! I clicked export on the cert in YubiKey Manager, and it exported a .crt file. The contents of that file are many more than 64 characters. It contains -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE----- lines, and 1264 hex chars in between.

You would need to open the certificate with something that knows how to read certificates. For instance, “openssl x509”

I suspect the problem is that my cert is ECC384. It looks like MS-recommended tool ("sign") only supports SHA based certs.

It is mentioned here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/dotnet-sign-cli-reference-vsix
that Sign CLI only supports RSA algorithms.

Currently it is not possible. Vote for it here:
Add support in Visual Studio 2015 and higher for ECDSA-SHA256 (and not only RSA-SHA256) for code-signing VSIX packages
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Add-support-in-Visual-Studio-2015-and-hi/10481797

Thanks. I think this is the answer right now. The (MS recommended) sign tool only supports RSA-SHA, but even if you use the OpenOpcSignTool in order to use ECDSA, users won't be able to install the signed VSIX. So either way, RSA-SHA is required to sign a VSIX. However, as far as I understand, RSA-SHA is not supported on a YubiKey. So, how is anyone signing VSIX archives currently?
